# Inherited app with strange routing error, No route matches {}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Whenever one of the mailers fires off if the body contains something like `link_to root_url` it gives this incredibly unhelpful error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {}
```

The trace either is useless or points to that `link_to` method. Since it's also very unsearchable here I am asking on stack overflow.

**UPDATE 1:** To help, I've posted the terrifying `routes.rb` file: https://gist.github.com/2955610

**UPDATE 2:** In the console, `app.root_url` provides the correct return.

**UPDATE 3:** `link_to "whatever", root_url` works just fine. So strange!

**UPDATE 4:** It works fine in a regular rails view.

**UPDATE 5:** *FIXED* The `image_tag` now isn't providing a host in the email, outputting: `http://assets/...png`. Fffff.

**UPDATE 6:** I've narrowed it down to that I get the same error with (in console) `app.url_for`. I think it may be related.

Comment: Just in case, do you have `root :to => "something"` in the routes.rb?

Comment: @dimuch I'll post my Routes file, watchout, it's ugly.

Comment: Could you also show few lines from templates that cause the error?

Comment: @dimuch It's nothing more than `<%= link_to root_url %>`

Comment: Have you tried `<%= link_to "root", root_url %>`?

Comment: @dimuch Ok, strange, that didn't error out.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html => read the "Generating URL" topic ;) I had the same error when started using mailers

Comment: I'm setting a host when using `root_url`, in my production.rb file:   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "www.connectforacause.com" }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the real answer is that `link_to` works differently in ActionMailer than in ActionController. The difference is that apparently ActionController has an option called `:script_name`, and this makes all sorts of assumptions for you.

Now while I don't agree with that difference there's not much you can do about it, so here's what I ended up doing:

```
link_to root_url, root_url
```

Now, why would I use both? Well two reasons:

1. I wanted the url as the anchor text and the href.
2. If the URL changes, I don't want to have to update all those strings.

Comment: it's incredible, I spent on this unexpected behavior more than 3 hours already. thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just lost a couple of hours dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with mailers is that maybe you miss "host" option? :)

Comment: In my `production.rb` file I have this set:   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "www.connectforacause.com" }`